# Annoying advertisement

Tags: security

I downloaded music using one of the youtube to mp3 converters, and I think that they infected my machine with some ad software. I keep getting a popup at the top of my screen every 30 min to 1 hour or so. How can I figure out what is causing this and fix it?

PS: I have Ubuntu 19.04. 
Also, I tried deleting the song file, but that didn't help. I downloaded the song using https://ytmp3.cc/en1/ (a Youtube to MP3 converter)

Comment: What did you download the file with?  `youtube-dl` or something else? or did you use a browser-extension (if so, is the browser still running in the background, what is the browser etc). I doubt it'd happen using `youtube-dl` or the like, but specifics are required to provide help.  Have you looked to see that browser isn't running (ie. a browser extension is preventing browser from exiting so it can remain in background (not on display) to put up message pop-ups - this is what I'd suspect you have; which is not Ubuntu related, bad browser addon at fault)

Comment: Also if you didn't add `youtube-dl` (or whatever you used given you didn't specify) using standard package tools (eg. `sudo apt install youtube-dl`) the method you used to add the tool & where from maybe helpful.

Comment: Where you using Firefox at any time in this process? If so, you've probably got a nasty cookie. Go to prefs and look at cookies, sorted by date, and delete any cookies that have a date close to when all of this happened... esp ones from sites that you don't recognize... ie:www.game_ads.com. Report back. Start comments to me with @heynnema or I may miss them.

Comment: @heynnema i did what you said it seemed like it worked thank you.

Comment: Also @guiverc thank you for letting me know about `youtube-dl` this is amazing! I didn't know it existed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the comments...

If you were using Firefox at any time in this process, you've probably got a nasty cookie. Go to Firefox preferences and look at cookies, sorted by date, and delete any cookies that have a date close to when all of this happened... especially ones from sites that you don't recognize...

ie: irritating_game_ads.com

Comment: You're very good at reading between the lines @heynnema and can solve issue no one else can!  [Big thumbs up!](http://i.stack.imgur.com/Q6z45.jpg)  (I already have you a small **+1**)

Comment: @Fabby thanks for the kind words, and the thumbs up!